# In rails 4 - how to process data from a controller into jquery for purposes of a progressbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and jquery/css and webapps in general. I need guidance in building progress bar functionality. My rails app basically inserts file data into an elasticsearch engine. The data is a user's uploaded csv/excel file.

From my controller, what is the best/cleanest way to get progress-bar type percentage from the controller into a coffeescript or jquery code. I'm clueless about how status-percentage type data from the server can be rendered in the view. Below I have the controller that is of relevance. The #upload page has a button that triggers the import action. The import action renders index action once the data is loaded into elasticsearch.

The FileProcessorService is just a ruby class that does the parsing of the file and inserting each record into elasticsearch and returns data.

Here is my controller:

```
class FileProcessorController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def import
        initialize_processor(params[:file])

        if (@file_sample != nil || @index_name != nil) then
            render 'index'
        end
    end

    def upload

    end

    def initialize_processor(file_in)

        File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', file_in.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
            file.write(file_in.read)
        end


        @file_processor = FileProcessorService.new(file_in)
        @file_sample = @file_processor.present_data_sample()
        @index_name = @file_processor.load_index()
    end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention you're "clueless" about how to approach this, I'll give you some ideas:

---

**Progress**

To handle a "progress bar", you're going to need away to receive regular updates at intervals. I don't know if `FileProcessorService` will do this - but your controller will need to send updates to your JS front-end somehow

Even if you don't have a percentage-based update from your controller, you'll want some event triggers to send updates to your system

---

[**Asynchronous**](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/asynchronous.html)

What you're dealing with is called an "asynchronous" request. This is a request outside the normal scope of HTTP requests, whereby your browser will initiate technology such as Javascript to send a request on your behalf

This basically means no refresh for the browser

You'll have to send an asynchronous request via JS, and then listen for the response. The response will be what determines your progress bar status

---

[**Pub/Sub**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)

Asynchronous functionality gives you two "methods" to send/receive data - ajax (single request) or pub/sub (multiple requests). Pub/sub is basically how *every* chat application sends data -- each user gets their own "channel" and the server sends updates to it

I would recommend using a Pub/Sub service called [`Pusher`](http://pusher.com) to achieve the "live" data updates, which you can tie to the progress bar's status

---

**Code**

I've not done this before, but this is what you'd need:

> 1. You'll need to send events from your controller to a pub/sub channel (Pusher highly recommended)
> 2. The user's browser will "listen" to the updates through Pusher - allowing you to assign progress bar status each time an update is
>      posted

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clearly explained. I'd like to create my own pusher endpoint that reports the status of the file. And my ajax request will be polling on the controller action that reports the file upload status. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem! Hope it helps & if you need any more info, please just ask!

Comment: Along the lines of the above. I've added a rails question about sharing state between controller methods without using active record. Could you advise? thank you so much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442117/is-a-rails-model-a-normal-ruby-class-that-can-be-used-to-store-state-between-dif